# Getting multiple COUNT in 1 query

Tags: sql, count

```
    id    name    type
---------------------
    1     a        ir
    2     b        sr
    3     a        ir
    4     a        sr
    5     b        ir
```

I want my output like this using COUNT in SQL

```
name  ir   sr
-------------
a     2     1
b     1     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE type WHEN 'ir' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ir,
       SUM(CASE type WHEN 'sr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sr
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name
```

In MySQL you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(type = 'ir') AS ir,
       SUM(type = 'sr') AS sr
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: How do i echo this in my php?

Comment: The same as any other query. You fetch the rows and echo `$row['name']`, `$row['ir']`, `$row['sr']`.